# Table Size Analysis on SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000

Our SQL Server 2000 database `.mdf` file is 27Gb large which seems much larger than is plausible. Using the following query we tried to analyse table sizes:

```
select cast(object_name(id) as varchar(50)) AS name,
    sum(CASE WHEN indid<2 THEN rows END) AS rows,
    sum(reserved)*8 AS reserved,
    sum(dpages)*8 AS data,
    sum(used-dpages)*8 AS index_size,
    sum(reserved-used)*8 AS unused
from sysindexes with (nolock)
    where indid in(0,1,255) and id>100 
    GROUP BY id with rollup
    ORDER BY sum(reserved)*8 desc
```

The results were as follows:

```
Name           Rows       Reserved  Data     Index_Size  Unused
NULL           15274279   26645456  5674592  17361464    3609400
BigTable         875966   16789712   471096  13349816    2968800
```

1. How can we find out which objects are causing this massive `NULL` space usage?
2. It seems that approx 26GB are "reserved" for `NULL`, 16GB for `BigTable` - is this basically a waste of space or are real records involved?

Comment: when did you last defragment? which service pack? Do you regularly run DBCC CHECKDB?

Comment: So what does `select id, reserved from sysindexes order by reserved desc;` yield? Also `BigTable` seems to have 13 GB worth of indexes, so I wonder about your definition of "waste of space"...

Comment: For a table of 470 MB you have 13.3 GB of indexes? Do you have an index for every combination of the columns?

Comment: You mean a disk defrag? Didn't know that would have any influence on the size of a single file. AFAIK our servers are virtual and using SAN technology.

Comment: Aaron, I get 1838629593 2028217 for tBigtable

Comment: There are 3 indexes on BigTable but they're all on trivial int fields. How to explain the 13GB??

Comment: I suppose the server is not reporting the correct space used by the tables. You could use the system procedure [sp_spaceused](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260286%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) (for each table) to see the reported space and if numbers don't match with what you think they should be, then use [DBCC UPDATEUSAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258283%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) (it will fix the row and page counts). Please read also [answer1](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/691/418) and [answer2](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2089/418).

Comment: You just need to write following command on query analyzer and run it will remove the spaces whatever table catering
user <database name>
dbcc shrinkfile ('<Database Name>')

Answer (score 2):

You're not using `WITH ROLLUP` correctly. `WTIH ROLLUP` creates a subtotal and/or total based upon what you tell it. You didn't specify what to call the subtotal and/or total so it is calling it `NULL`.

This query generates a subtotal report:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (GROUPING(Item) = 1) THEN 'ALL'
            ELSE ISNULL(Item, 'UNKNOWN')
       END AS Item,
       CASE WHEN (GROUPING(Color) = 1) THEN 'ALL'
            ELSE ISNULL(Color, 'UNKNOWN')
       END AS Color,
       SUM(Quantity) AS QtySum
FROM Inventory
GROUP BY Item, Color WITH ROLLUP
```

Output:

```
Item                 Color                QtySum                     
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------------- 
Chair                Blue                 101.00                     
Chair                Red                  210.00                     
Chair                ALL                  311.00                     
Table                Blue                 124.00                     
Table                Red                  223.00                     
Table                ALL                  347.00                     
ALL                  ALL                  658.00
```

Comment: This is neither helpful nor "correct". It is a matter of taste whether a rollup of a null value should display 'UKNOWN' or what-have-you (using CASE) and it's irrelevant to this question.

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer. They overlooked this important thing in the question.